# Create binary raster with a spatial condition for generating cell values

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, r

I have a raster grid. Cells either have the value 0 (blank in the example image below*) or NA

[image]

I need to designate some non-NA cells with the value of 1 with the following rule:

- Cells with a value of 1 cannot touch another cell with a value of 1 (i.e. the surrounding 8 cells must have a value of 0 or NA)

Here is a visual example, where cells with a value of 1 are black

[image]

My problem is I have no idea how to generate this using ArcGIS or R. Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

*The actual grid has ~15000 cells

Comment: By asking how to do the same thing in either of two products you are effectively asking two questions which makes this too broad for focused Q&A.  Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to focus your question on one or other.  I recommend asking about the one you are most likely to use.  You can always ask about the other one in a separate question.

Comment: Multiple (countless?) solutions are possible. Example given valid because you started with upper left cell.

Comment: Very valid point about the multiple solutions. I think the best thing is if I go back to my collaborators to discuss this and @Elio-Diaz answer. Clearly we need to refine the question/rules further.

I

Answer (score 1):

The following loop tests a sample of all cells, first, if cell value is 0, it tests wether the top and lower cells are not `NA` with the `tb` matrix, and if the 8 surrounding cells are not 1 (`sum` evaluations); then it substitutes for 1 if the conditions are is met; you may search in the documentation for `raster::adjacent` to adjust the parameters. If you want to do it for more cells (or all cells) modify the `sample` parameteres.

```
# for 1521 cells (as your raster) it takes ~ 3 seconds
library(raster)
ke = sample(c(NA,0,0, 0), 1521, replace = T) # three 0 to have less NA
kem = matrix(ke, nrow = 39)
ker = raster(kem)

tb = matrix(c(NA, 1, NA,
              NA, 0, NA,
              NA, 1, NA), byrow = T, ncol = 3)

ker1 = ker # just for the plot

for(i in sort(sample(1:length(ker), 100))){
  if(!is.na(ker[i]) & ker[i] == 0) {           
    tba = adjacent(ker, cells = i, directions = tb, pairs = F)
    a8 = adjacent(ker, cells = i, directions = 8, pairs = F)
        if(sum(is.na(ker[tba])) == 0 & sum(ker[a8], na.rm = T) == 0){  #not NA and no 1 next
      ker[i] = 1    # set 1 to that raster cell
    } 
  }
}

par(mar = c(1,1,1,1), mfrow = c(1,2))
plot(ker1, col = c("blue"), legend = F, axes = F, box = F)
text(ker1, cex = .8)
plot(ker, col = c("blue", "red"), legend = F, axes = F, box = F)
text(ker, cex = .8)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this - it gives us something to work with (as discussed in the comments on the original question, there are multiple answers so we need to refine our problem before moving forward).